# Contact us page configuration

Tags: contacts

http://webmaster.hostkill.info/Contact/

I want help regarding how to configure this contact page. I would be very thankful if someone would guide me.

Comment: Are you really building a site using local URIs to link to your pages, assets and stylesheets and then putting it online?

Comment: no no its just for u to view it and help me regarding how to configure the contact page which is the submittion of comments to my email ..

Answer (score 0):

All the links in your HTML that file:/// are absolute to your filesystem and won't work online.

All paths have to be relative to your application's base folder or absolute including the url of the website.

Your `<form` tag doesn't have an action and your submit button doesn't submit.

I suggest you google for an example in php or .net

Comment: thanks but i guess u didnt get it lemme clear u i knw all things regarding uploads but i want to configure this contact page such as the mailings the submittion of comments to my e-mail thats what i want to configure "the use of Contact Page" and i uploaded this page for u guys to view it and help me and my website is still in designing process

Answer (score 0):

correct all the links. If you have all files in one folder [as far as I see you have this structure] correct the links from this `<a href="file:///H|/My Work/Gamma/Gamma/template/index.html"` to this `<a href="index.html"`
The same for css files on the `<head>` tag

Comment: sir no link problem sry for my bad english as it is not my first language which lacks u to understand my problem , my problem is i dont knw how to configure the contact page mean submittion of comment to my email plz help me regarding this

Comment: to test it locally you have run for example php on your machine. you can download wamp which include php,msql. When the php is installed on your machine you have to follow the followings step as you find them at http://www.kirupa.com/web/php_contact_form.htm
1.you create a form [as you already have done]
2.on your form create an action and a method
3.you give name on your input fields
4.you create a php file which receive the data when submit is clicked [same name with form's action]
5.take the data of fields and save them on php variables
5.you print them on screen or send them with e-mail

Comment: tell me yours if you wish and I contact you :)

Comment: ok just mail me with sotiris from sof :)
mas_forums@hotmail.com